# Laravel Custom PasswordBroker not sending password reset link email

Tags: php, laravel, docker, email

I'm using customized password reset function in Laravel.
`Laravel version 5.8`

I followed this document https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passwords#password-customization
And also adding custom guard I checked here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards

I don't know what I'm doing wrong with these settings below.

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'customers' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'customers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\CustomerLoginInfo::class,
        ],

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
//        'users' => [
//            'provider' => 'users',
//            'table' => 'password_resets',
//            'expire' => 60,
//        ],

        'customers' => [
            'provider' => 'customers',
            'table' => 'customer_password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('customers');
    }

    /**
     * Validate the email for the given request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['login_email' => 'required|email']);
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authentication credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('login_email');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/form/03';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:customers');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('customers');
    }

    protected function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('customers');
    }
}
```

My Model extends authenticatable

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class CustomerLoginInfo extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'customer_login_info';

    protected $fillable = ['customer_id', 'login_email', 'password'];

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customer');
    }

    public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
    {
        return $this->login_email;
    }
}
```

Even though I get success message I don't receive password reset link email.

[image]

I'm using docker mailhog and I don't have any problem receiving other kinds of mails.

If you found anything weird in this code please let me know.

Comment: does any record added to your `customer_password_resets` table after request?

Comment: @HafezDivandari Yes, email address, token and timestamps.

Comment: Are you using queue to send mails? If yes does any record added to your `jobs` or `failed_jobs` table? any log report on `storage/logs`?

Comment: @HafezDivandari No I'm not using queue, so I don't see any record in my laravel log.

Comment: Try to change you mail driver to log and check if any emails are sent to log. on your `.env` file change this `MAIL_DRIVER=log`

Comment: @HafezDivandari I changed MAIL_DRIVER=log and I see no log when send email.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207096/discussion-between-hanachan1026-and-hafez-divandari).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replying to myself, I found a solution, I digged into this problem for hours and in Laravel 5.8 you need

```
public function routeNotificationForMail($notification)
{
        return $this->login_email;
}
```

in your authenticatable, if you are using email column's name other than email.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#customizing-the-recipient